# Column-by-Column cbind of lm output

Tags: r, cbind

I'd like to do a column-by-column comparison of two lm outputs. Something like this except I'd like to see the estimates next to the estimates nest to the estimates, the Std Error next to the Std Error, etc.

```
    x=runif(6);y=runif(6);z=runif(6)
    x2=runif(6);y2=runif(6);z2=runif(6)
    lm1=lm(x~z+y)
    lm2=lm(x2~z2+y2)
    s=summary(lm1)[["coefficients"]]
    s2=summary(lm2)[["coefficients"]]
    > cbind(s,s2)
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)   Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.67359508  0.8137390  0.8277778 0.4684978  0.6944551  0.2398032  2.895938 0.06270911
z           -0.19911923  1.0491558 -0.1897899 0.8615892  1.2509814  0.5678805  2.202896 0.11486078
y           -0.07097291  0.4569228 -0.1553280 0.8864254 -0.8926959  0.4984554 -1.790924 0.17123009
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# column bind
res <- cbind(s,s2)

# make unique column names
colnames(res) <- make.unique(colnames(res))

# sort column names
ix <- order(colnames(res))

# result
res[,ix]

# output

#               Estimate Estimate.1  Pr(>|t|) Pr(>|t|).1 Std. Error Std. Error.1    t value t value.1
# (Intercept)  1.7701957 0.09783934 0.5505218  0.7042956  2.6399847    0.2342630  0.6705325 0.4176475
# z            0.2393442 0.45691026 0.8111899  0.6096530  0.9180588    0.8041508  0.2607068 0.5681898
# y           -1.7020430 0.12906057 0.6185858  0.8798162  3.0758497    0.7846930 -0.5533570 0.1644727
```